# System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView does not display data

Tags: datagridview, c#-4.0

All I am doing is a simple:

```
    // Both the methods, order.GetAllOrderItems() and order.GetOrderedItemsWhereBrandIs("foo")
    // return an IEnumerable<T> so the assignment to the DataSource property of the DataGridView
    // should be fine. The problem is in re-assigning the data source property.
    public void DisplayItems()
    {
        // The data appears if I have just this line.
        dgvOrderedItems.DataSource = order.GetAllOrderItems();

        dgvOrderedItems.DataSource = null;

        // This time the data grid does not take the new data source. Instead, because
        // of the null assignment in the previous statement, it displays no data at all.
        dgvOrderedItems.DataSource = order.GetOrderedItemsWhereBrandIs("Lenovo");
    }
```

My question is: is there a way to change the data source of a DataGridView control once it has been set? I am using C# 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010 for development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Databinding cannot be used with `IEnumerable`s; you can only bind to an `IList` or better.

Add `.ToArray()` to turn the `IEnumerable` into an `IList<T>`.

The reason it works the first time is probably because your `GetAllOrderItems` doesn't perform any LINQ calls and ends up returning an object that implements `IList`.

However, since your `GetOrderedItemsWhereBrandIs` method (presumably) includes a `Where()` call, it returns an object that only implements `IEnumerable`.